# How to call a parent class component function from named functional component

Tags: reactjs

//parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import function1, { function2 } from "./functionalComponent";

class ParentClass extends Component {
state = {  loading: true  };

doAction = () => { this.setState({ loading : !this.state.loading })

render() {
    return (<function1 props={this.state} doAction={this.doAction}/>);
}
```

//child.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

const function1 = data => {
return(
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => data.doAction()}>
            Click
          </button>

          <button onClick={() => function2()}>
            Click
          </button>
        </div>
      );
}

const function2 = data => {
 axios
   .patch(`${getInStorage("baseUrl")}/api/v2/job_applications/${id}/shortlistt`)
   .then(() => {
                 data.doAction();         //throws error
               })
}

export { function2 };
export default function1;
```

From the fuction1 component I can access parent class function but from function2 component how can i access the same function

As function2 does not return anything still I imported that component and tried this code but cannot call the method.

```
render() {
    return (<function1 props={this.state} doAction={this.doAction}>
               <function2 doAction={this.doAction}/>
            </function1>);
}
```

Any solution to call the method.

Comment: you forgot to pass data param to your function `<button onClick={() => function2(data)}>`

Comment: @buzatto Thanks man pointing my small mistake